# Sentence Structure Questions

Tags: sentence-structure, tense

Es ist nichts verborgen, was nicht offenbar **werden wird**, und nichts geheim, was man nicht **wissen wird**.

1.what is the name of the structure used in this sentence?

2.In order to use this structure what are the key points i have to remember?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "sentence structure". Why are "werden wird" and "wissen wird" emphasized? What exactly is it that you need help with understanding?

Comment: @HalvarF Thank you, i need help understanding "werden wird" and "wissen wird"

Comment: @iamshimye You should try to understand a sentence (or a clause) on a whole, not just two words of it. Did you understand the sentence except for the words in bold? That does not seem to make sense.

Comment: As the others explained: the verbs are Futur I of werden and wissen respectively

Comment: By the way, don't forget to accept answers to your questions. It's not mandatory, but it's an indicator of which answer you found most useful. You've posted 12 questions here and accepted none of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

The top level structure is just 2 main clauses connected by "und".

> Es ist nichts verborgen und es ist nichts geheim.

Then the repetitive part is omitted

> Es ist nichts verborgen und nichts geheim.

There is probably some term for that, but I don't remember it right now.

Next, each of those clauses gets their respective relative clause.

Comment: Thank you, i need help understanding "werden wird" and "wissen wird"

Comment: @iamshimye: Those are just future tense, not related to the structure of the sentence. Meaning "will become" and "will know". Because they are in a subordinate clause the auxiliary verb is in the end.

Answer (score 1):

This is very elementary German grammar and thus not well suited for German SE but nonetheless I will try to explain it.

As you probably know, "werden" and "wissen" are infinitives. "wird" is 3rd person singular indicative present of "werden", which here is used as an auxiliary verb to form the future tense (Futur I) with the respective infinitive.

As for why "wird" is after the infinitive: It is part of a subodinate clause, and in this kind of subordinate clause (a relative clause, actually) the finite verb is placed at the end of the clause.

Comment: I don't think there should be a limit on questions being "too elementary", as long the poster has done due diligence and the answer isn't easily available in a dictionary, etc.

Comment: Well, the closing criteria mention conjugation tables, and with some lack of goodwill this might apply here.

Answer (score 1):

There are two clauses with slightly different grammar. Both of these clauses consist of a main clause and a subordinate clause introduced by the relative pronoun "*was*". You can analyze first relative clause, as the future tense of "*werden*" = "to become". So "*Das wird nicht offenbar.*" = "That does not become revealed." In the future tense this is "*Das wird nicht offenbar werden.*" = "That will not become revealed." And in a relative clause it's "*... was nicht offenbar werden wird.*" = "... which will not become revealed." Note that the auxiliary verb to form the future tense is the same as the main verb, "*werden*". Also note that in a subordinate clause, the main verb is moved to the end.

In the second relative clause, the main verb is "*wissen*" in the future tense. In this case the subject is "*man*", meaning "one", or "you" (people in general). Literally "*Man weiß das nicht*" means "One does not know that", but in English it's more natural to use the passive voice in this case: "That is not known." In the future tense this is "*Man wird das nicht wissen.*" = "That will not be known." And in a relative clause: "*... was man nicht wissen wird.*" = "... which will not be known."

This isn't a special structure with its own name, just a combination of the future tense and a relative clause. Remember that features of a languages can be combined in an almost infinite number of ways in a singe sentence, so it would be impossible to have names for every combination. A double negative used twice here. This makes the sentence a bit harder to decipher, but it serves to emphasize the "secret/hidden" part over what is "known/revealed".